# Arguments of the Kalman Filter in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, kalman-filter

We have been trying to use Kalman filter to improve our trajectory prediction code. I have looked at some online resources and understood most of the part of how it is used in opencv but what I am unable to understand is the constructor call to KalmanFilter in OpenCV.

`KalmanFilter KF(2, 1, 0);`

What do 2, 1 and 0 here represent?

**Update**: Finally figured out the meaning of the arguments by printing or the sizes of the various matrices involved.

State: 2x1

State transition matrix: 2x2

Control matrix: 0x0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=kalman#kalmanfilter-kalmanfilter), the 2,1, and 0 are the dimensionalities of the state, measurements, and control spaces.

That is, your state vector has length 2, measurements are scalars, and there is no control signal.

Comment: Does the 0 mean that there is no control signal?

Comment: It means that the control vector dimensionality is zero. That implies a zero control signal.